# UISearchBar completely custom background

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uiappearance

I am trying to change the appearance of an UISearchBar to obtain the following result

[Custom Search Bar http://imageshack.com/a/img194/3835/jhl7.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img194/3835/jhl7.png)

I tried with UIAppearance methods, and also by removing the UISearchBarBackground, but it seems that the border of the textfield cannot be removed.

The best result i obtained is :

[image: actual search bar]

The problem is not the magnifying glass, but the border :)

Comment: Could you post some code perhaps?

Comment: What is your bar style?

Comment: @KirillProkopovich: The bar style is the default one, changing to black or black translucent will not solve my problem anyway.

Comment: @PaulPeelen everything is done in IB except this : [[UISearchBar appearance] setSearchFieldBackgroundImage: [[UIImage imageNamed: @"background-search"]
                                                              resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 7.0, 0, 7.0)]
                                               forState: UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: If my answer don't help you. I offer use just textfield for search, which be subview of any UIImageView (background). You can found text field special for search https://github.com/mark0dark/TextFieldForSearchBar

Comment: Maybe it would work better to just use a normal `UITextField`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set clear color to your serch bar:

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Or try:

```
UIImage *searchBg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Search_Background.png"];
searchBg = [searchBg stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:10]; //experiment with values
 [[UISearchBar appearance] setSearchFieldBackgroundImage: [[UIImage imageNamed: @"background-search"];
```

Comment: No it does not works, this is what i obtained with a clear color : http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/6342/rcfr.png

Comment: well setBackgroundImage alone did not solve the problem, but this AND the setSearchFieldBackgroundImage worked for the search bar. I have to check for the scopes now.

Comment: Everything is now working as expected. Thanks Kirill, also if you can add the "setSearchFieldBackgroundImage" to your answer :)